# Is there a way to generate a huge amount of custom pcac for testing purposes?

Tags: pcap

I have a segment of code i want to stress test that's reading through pcap data. But i have no easy way of generating the type of pcap that i want without illegitimately collecting in a public area.

So does anyone know a tool or method that can be used to make a large pcap sample size for testing in order to properly test my code?

Comment: Do you want a diverse set of packets or a large pcap with only a few different packets is enough?

Comment: @pchaigno Both, the idea is to capture a huge base of wifi packets that i can then query for information. So a large diverse group of packets would be ideal. It could be the same 10000 packets 100 times. But i do need a way to make those initial 10000 packets.

Comment: I really just need a lot of unique packets that i can filter through and retain without worrying about infringing on someones privacy. Hence the need for a generator or tool to create the pcap. text2pcap is useful but hand crafting that many packets would take way to long to do unfortunately.

Comment: Why can't you collect your own WiFi traffic?

Comment: Collecting isn't the issue the issue is retaining it. The last i heard retaining public scans was not cool. So i just want to avoid any potential issues with that and just generate my own traffic that i have control over. Plus running public scans may not get me the traffic i need to properly stress test my code with the proper packets.

Comment: Why can't you retain only your own WiFi traffic? Don't put your adapter in promiscuous mode and listen on the corresponding interface.

Comment: I don't have the devices to generate the traffic types I'm looking for at home. Which is why im just trying to generate the traffic i need.

Comment: Searching the same 3-5 devices wouldnt really put a proper test on the code im trying to test so i need a way to make 1000's of devices worth of traffic. This would be easily accomplished with a traffic generator of some kind. I just dont know any good ones to use or if there even is one that i can use to make something like that.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I can't provide a definitive answer as I've never done this myself. Looks like [the LANforge software](https://www.candelatech.com/cookbook.php?vol=wifire&book=wifi+testing) can do what you want though.

Comment: That is actually a great tool for what i need but i dont have the money laying around to purchase that haha, do you know a free or open source version that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: No, sorry. Note that they seem to provide [free licenses for non-profit use cases](https://www.candelatech.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=lanforge-faq#how_do_i_obtain_a_free_student_or_non-profit_license) (in case your a student or researcher).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Ill look into that since i am currently enrolled as a student haha!

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions that you can consider:

- randpkt: a random packet generator https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/randpkt.html
- Duplicate a small number of pcap files hundreds of times then merge them using `mergecap` https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html

  mergecap -w out.pcap in1.pcap in1.pcap in1.pcap in2.pcap in2.pcap ...
- Generate the traffic you need and record it, you can use `tgn` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tgn.1.html for example to generate the traffic, and `tcpdump` to record it.